# Electron Amplify AppSync "Realtime disabled when in a server-side environment"

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm using amplify appsync in my electron app and all works except for the realtime events which means my app doesn't get signalled when the data changes in the cloud.

I know this is because it's running in Node which is what amplify is looking for (JS.browserOrNode) however I don't know how to fix it. Can someone advise me how I can get the realtime updates? When I query it just gets the local data unless I Datastore.stop() and Datastore.start() but surely there's a better way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you tried `amplify api gql-compile` and then `amplify codegen`, maybe you not updated your schema

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ifaruki, it was all set up right it was just electron blocking it, please see my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the amplify team on discord for this one, in amplify-js the logic for the browser vs node check is:

```
const browserOrNode = () => {
    const isBrowser =
        typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.document !== 'undefined';
    const isNode =
        typeof process !== 'undefined' &&
        process.versions != null &&
        process.versions.node != null;

    return {
        isBrowser,
        isNode,
    };
};
```

The Datastore logic determines whether it's going to spit that warning or start the subscriptions:

```
if (isNode) {
    logger.warn(
        'Realtime disabled when in a server-side environment'
    );
} else {
    //#region GraphQL Subscriptions
    [
        // const ctlObservable: Observable<CONTROL_MSG>
        ctlSubsObservable,
        // const dataObservable: Observable<[TransformerMutationType, SchemaModel, Readonly<{
        // id: string;
        // } & Record<string, any>>]>
        dataSubsObservable,
    ] = this.subscriptionsProcessor.start();
}
```

But because Electron runs the app in a Node.js environment it's why DataStore is disabling realtime.

You can stop this by forcing isNode to be false and then realtime works with electron :)

Comment: But what if I need node integration?

Comment: It's just a setting for amplify to allow real-time, it doesn't change anything else in the app @Lance

Comment: How can I 'force' it to be false? did you fork the repo?

Comment: No I patched it @margincall !

[See here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

Answer (score 1):

Thank @S.Mac,

A more clarification on S.Mac answer how I fixed mine.

```json
"node version": "v19.2.0",
"npm version": "9.2.0",
"aws-amplify": "^5.0.4",
"patch-package": "^6.5.0"
```

1. Open package.json and add `"postinstall": "patch-package"` to `script`
2. Install patch-package `npm i patch-package` or `npm i --save-dev patch-package`
   if you prefer
3. Open "node_module/@aws-amplify/core/lib-ems/JS.js" and scroll down to

```js
export var browserOrNode = function(){}
```

and replace all the statement in with

```js
return {
  isBrowser: true,
  isNode: false,
};
```

4. Open "node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/src/JS.ts" and find
   `export const browserOrNode = () => {}` function if you're using TS and change the statement in to:

```js
const isBrowser = true;
const isNode = false;

return {
  isBrowser,
  isNode,
};
```

5. Now finally, patch the package back using : `npx patch-package aws-amplify` ensure you're connected to internet, i don't know why.

Hope this will be helpfull to someone and me.

Comment: Did you find the issue come back with the latest update of amplify? not server side disabled, looks like it still works but max subscriptions reached doesnt respect the subscriptions within the boundary. all or nothing type scenario